# When to use URL attribute for both Collection and Model?

Tags: backbone.js

I've been following some Backbone.js tutorials and am a bit confused about when to use 'url' inside Model when there is also a Collection which contains the model. For example I see a lot of code that looks like this, in order to synchronize with the server:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var PostsModel = Bacbone.Collection.extend({
  model: PostModel,
  url: "/posts"
});
```

However I also see some where the model also has 'url' property, like so:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "/posts"
});
var PostsModel = Bacbone.Collection.extend({
  model: PostModel,
  url: "/posts"
});
```

I think I understand the first method, where I interact with the models only through the collections to which they belong, but I am not sure when you would want to have urls for both a model and its collection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need a model that doesn't belong to any collection.

For example a `login`/`sign in`.

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/login"
});
```

This way you can interact with `login` view and model just like you would with any other `Backbone` model, including `save()` (which posts the login form to the server) and validation.

There is however no `login` collection, so it doesn't make sense to model that.

Maybe the code you're seeing is something in between. Models are accessed via collection in some places of the application and without collection in others.

If it's a good design is another story, but there's no technical reason to not do it.

**edit**
As you noticed, using `urlRoot` is another option, since by default the `url` attribute is a method that uses `urlRoot` to construct the relative url. 
It can be, however, given a string value to specify the model url directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However this leads me to another confusion. I thought you should use urlRoot to set the url for a model if it doesn't belong to a collection, no?

Comment: By the way, this is where I see a usage of urlRoot for a model which already belongs to a collection: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-2-crud/

Comment: yeah, it's a bit confusing. I'd use `urlRoot` for that too (and use the default `Model.url` implementation), but that doesn't stop you from simply putting an url directly in `Model.url`

Comment: whre did you see that Post/Posts model example? cause it doesn't really make to much sense :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't remember where I saw exactly the example where both a model and its collection had the same 'url' attribute. But the link I posted above in this thread does have a model with 'urlRoot' and collection with 'url', which point to the same url, which I think is also weird. Isn't it?

Comment: @Vlad yeah, it's confusing. I don't think `urlRoot` is needed if you create model and connect it to collection before saving (which the author of that blog post doesn't do).

Comment: I just found this post on Github: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1593 If I understand correctly, according to this, I think we should not really be using url inside model. It's either urlRoot for a model that doesn't belong to any collection, or in case it *does* belong to a collection (or multiple collections) we should be using 'url' inside each collection...

Comment: yes. `url` is supposed to be used very sparingly and in general shouln't be needed.